# How to map through api data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building a app using a country api and which displays information such as name, population and region of a country. 
I want to display the languages, currencies and borders with the country. 
Ive tried to map the data to display the borders but it's saying map is undefined.

```
<div>
    // this works and displays
    <h1>{info.name}</h1>
    <p>Population: {info.population}</p>
    <p>Region: {info.region}</p>
    <p>Capital: {info.capital}</p>
    <h4>Languages:</h4> 
    // this gives the error 'cannot map of undefined'
    <ul>
        {info.borders.map((border) => {
          return <li key={border.name}>{border.name}</li>; })}
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is the response data i'm using

```
data:
name: "Brazil"
topLevelDomain: [".br"]
alpha2Code: "BR"
alpha3Code: "BRA"
callingCodes: ["55"]
capital: "Brasília"
altSpellings: (4) ["BR", "Brasil", "Federative Republic of Brazil", "República Federativa do Brasil"]
region: "Americas"
subregion: "South America"
population: 206135893
latlng: (2) [-10, -55]
demonym: "Brazilian"
area: 8515767
gini: 54.7
timezones: (4) ["UTC-05:00", "UTC-04:00", "UTC-03:00", "UTC-02:00"]
borders: (10) ["ARG", "BOL", "COL", "GUF", "GUY", "PRY", "PER", "SUR", "URY", "VEN"]
nativeName: "Brasil"
numericCode: "076"
currencies: [{…}]
languages: [{…}]
```

Below is how I'm getting the data

```js
const Infopage = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

  const code = useParams().alpha3Code;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('info');
    axios
      .get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${code}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setInfo(response.data);
      });

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <CountryInfo info={info} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Infopage;
```

Ive tried this with the same issue

```
 const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const code = useParams().alpha3Code;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await axios.get(
        `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${code}`
      );
      setInfo(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [code]);

  return (
    <div>{isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : <CountryInfo info={info} />}</div>
```

Comment: FYI, just to be clear, it's not saying that `map` is undefined, it's saying that your `borders` property is not defined, thus it can't access the `map` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: With destructuring and assign default value for borders.

```
const { borders = [] } =  info;

// use `borders` directly
  <ul>
    {borders.map((border) => {
      return <li key={border.name}>{border.name}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
```

Option 2: Check for undefined/null values

```
  <ul>
    {info && info.borders && info.borders.length > 0 && info.borders.map((border) => {
      return <li key={border.name}>{border.name}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
```

Comment: I've edited the code above to show my info state and how I'm receiving the data. Would your suggestions still apply to the update?

Comment: This has worked and now I can display borders. However could you help me understand why I had to do this please? I would like to learn.

Comment: @DGB, Glad to hear that its working.  When first time component loaded are you doing 2 things 1) Request for loading info and 2) Rendering the component (during this time info is empty does not aware of borders, So to have guard this, you need add the either conditional rendering or have default values/array.  Now after some time (ms or seconds), you will receive the response from API and then re-render happen (during this time you have valid data, so it renders as you expect). you also need to take care when API response is error or empty, even for this you need to have same checks as above.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell based on your question, but I'd wager a guess that `info` is an empty object, and JavaScript gives you `undefined` for every property access. Because the other properties are used as is, no exception is thrown, but because you try to call a method on `.borders`, that line throws an exception.

If that's the case, it's possible that it's because you use `const [info, setInfo] = useState({})` and rely on `useEffect` to populate the object. This would mean that on *first* render (at the minimum) and until any asynchronous work in `useEffect` resolves, the initial value is returned by `useState`. If that's the case, you should show a loading state (or no data) until it is populated. Remember that React may render your component multiple times for any reason, so don't rely on render count or ordering.

Add details as to how you are getting your data if possible. If not, add a breakpoint (or a `console.log`) before you try to build your React element (the `<div>`.

Comment: Ive edited to show how I'm getting my data. I get what your'e saying about loading state and tried to implement it. However I was unable to get it to work or understand how. Is it a case of setting loading to true then when data is fetched back to false?